# Pigstorage to read zipped file in pig script

Tags: zip, apache-pig, php-ziparchive

I have a program which dumps tab separated data file zipped to S3.

I have a Pig script which loads data from the S3 bucket. I have specified the .zip extension in the file name so that Pig knows the compression used.

The pig scripts runs and dumps data back into S3.

The logs shows that it is processing records but the dumped files are all empty.

Here is an extract from the logs

```
Input(s):
Successfully read 375 records (435 bytes) from: "s3://<bucket-name>/<job-id>/test-folder/filename1.zip"
Successfully read 444 records (442 bytes) from: "s3://<bucket-name>/<job-id>/test-folder/filename2.zip"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 375 records (1605 bytes) in: "s3://<bucket-name>/<job-id>/test-folder/output/output1-folder"
Successfully stored 444 records (1814 bytes) in: "s3://<bucket-name>/<job-id>/test-folder/output/output2-folder"
Successfully stored 0 records in: "s3://<bucket-name>/<job-id>/test-folder/output/output3-folder"
```

The code to load and store data is:

```
data1 = load '$input1'
    using PigStorage('\t') as
    (field1:long,
     field2:long,
     field3:double
);

data2 = load '$input2'
    using PigStorage('\t') as
    (field1:long,
     field2:long,
     field3:double
);

store output1 into '$output1-folder'
    using PigStorage('\t', '-schema');

store output2 into '$output2-folder'
    using PigStorage('\t', '-schema');

store output3 into '$output3-folder'
    using PigStorage('\t', '-schema');
```

Code to compress file

```
public static void compressFile(String originalArchive, String zipArchive) throws IOException {
    try (
            ZipOutputStream archive = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipArchive));
            FileInputStream file    = new FileInputStream(originalArchive);
    ) {
        final int bufferSize = 100 * 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        archive.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(zipArchive));

        int count = 0;
        while ((count = file.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                archive.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        file.close();
        archive.closeEntry();
        archive.close();

    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you do the following: 1. Delete s3://<bucket-name>/<job-id>/test-folder/output/output1-folder (and check that it is gone) 2. Run the code 3. Check the properties of s3://<bucket-name>/<job-id>/test-folder/output/output1-folder (size, last edit date, actual content if you open it)